# Finding text in a cell

Tags: nlp, stata

I am playing with an exercise of text finding in Stata.

```
clear 
input id postid str7 text str3 referencedtext ref_postid
1 1 "XYZ ABC" "" .
1 2 "BCD ABC" "ABC" 1
1 3 "DCE" "" .
2 1 "XYZ" "" .
2 2 "ABC" "" .
2 3 "JKL" "" .
2 4 "JKL DEF" "JKL" 3
end
```

I am attempting to find what `postid` within the same thread that `referencedtext` comes from (i.e., who is a given poster referencing) and create a new variable `ref_postid` that signifies the referenced post's `postid`. The `referencedtext` may include all of the original `text` that it is referencing from, or only a piece. There may also be capitalization differences, so dealing with that would be helpful.

This is what I used:

```
gen ref_postid = .
qui bys id (postid) : sum postid
local postidmax= r(max) 
qui forval i = 1/`postidmax' { 
    bys id (postid): replace ref_postid = postid[_n-`i'] if referencedtext == text[_n-`i'] & referencedtext != "" & postid != 1
}
```

Comment: @NickCox (1) and (2) were typos that are now fixed. (2) was not an issue originally but an error occurred to help aid your understanding. (3) is a coding issue and I am open to a fix. (4) is because how can the initial post in a thread reference something in a thread that does not exist? (logically impossible). The text of the question has been clear since the outset and I would imagine is a common issue

Comment: @NickCox The "text of the question has been clear since the outset" is the statement I made. I made no such statement about the code. Without my attempt (which obviously does not work), but I always like to provide my own attempt, the question stands clearly. As for (2) 3 is the right answer because `id == 2 & postid == 4` has `referencedtext == JKL` which is only seen, within the `id == 2`, when `postid == 3`

Comment: @NickCox Well this back and forth helped me derive the answer so thank you

Comment: Good that you made progress. I don't understand everything about this but I think I can remove the loop. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some back and forth with Nick, this solution works. Using `strpos` helps eliminate the need for an exact match and reducing the text to lowercase is helpful in maximizing the matches. Although, depending on text length this may be best replaced with an exact match requirement.

```
replace text = lower(text)
replace referencedtext = lower(referencedtext)
gen ref_postid = .
qui su postid
local maxposts = r(max) 
forval i = 1/`maxposts' {
    qui bys id (postid) : replace ref_postid = postid[_n-`i'] if strpos(text[_n-`i'],referencedtext) >= 1 & postid != 1 & referencedtext != ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to rewrite the answer from @CJ12 without a loop. It reproduces the solution requested. Whether it breaks some other assumption remains open for comment.

```
clear 
input id postid str7 text str3 referencedtext 
1 1 "XYZ ABC" "" 
1 2 "BCD ABC" "ABC" 
1 3 "DCE" "" 
2 1 "XYZ" "" 
2 2 "ABC" "" 
2 3 "JKL" "" 
2 4 "JKL DEF" "JKL" 
end 

gen text2 = lower(text)
bysort id (referenced): gen refer2 = lower(referenced[_N])
gen found = strpos(text2, refer2) > 0 
gsort id -found postid 
by id: gen ref_postid = postid[1] if found 
replace ref_postid = . if missing(referenced) 
sort id postid 

list, sepby(id) 

     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   postid      text   refere~t     text2   refer2   found   ref_po~d |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1        1   XYZ ABC              xyz abc      abc       1          . |
  2. |  1        2   BCD ABC        ABC   bcd abc      abc       1          1 |
  3. |  1        3       DCE                  dce      abc       0          . |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |  2        1       XYZ                  xyz      jkl       0          . |
  5. |  2        2       ABC                  abc      jkl       0          . |
  6. |  2        3       JKL                  jkl      jkl       1          . |
  7. |  2        4   JKL DEF        JKL   jkl def      jkl       1          3 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```